# How to change root in react-native-router-flux?

Tags: react-native, react-native-router-flux

I'm using react-native-router-flux v4, This is my Router component:

```
const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <stack key="auth">
          <Scene
            key="login"
            component={LoginForm}
            title="Please Login"
          />
        </stack>
        <stack key="main">
          <Scene
            key="RestaurantListing"
            component={RestaurantListing}
            title="Restaurants available"
          />
        </stack>
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  )
};
```

When I go to main, I see "RestaurantListing" component, but I still see the back arrow(<-) in the top navigation ?

I don't want the user to be able to go back to authentication page, How can I do that ?

Answer (score 0):

You should first add hideNavBar as a prop to the scene RestaurantListing, or you could add it to main if none of main's children are going to use the navbar. You will also need to import ActionConst from 'react-native-router-flux' and set the type prop of main to ActionConst.RESET which resets the stack, thus removing your auth pages from the back stack.

```js
import { Scene, Router, ActionConst } from 'react-native-router-flux';

const RouterComponent = () => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <Scene key="root">
        <stack key="auth">
          <Scene
            key="login"
            component={LoginForm}
            title="Please Login"
          />
        </stack>
        <stack key="main" type={ActionConst.RESET}>
          <Scene
            key="RestaurantListing"
            component={RestaurantListing}
            title="Restaurants available"                
            hideNavBar
          />
        </stack>
      </Scene>
    </Router>
  )
};
```

Comment: Dear Joe, thank you so much for answering this question, but this question was asked 6 months ago. Facing this problem made me choose react-navigation lib, apart from the other reason that it's supported by react-native and redux as well. I really don't want to confirm that this is the right answer unless someone else tries it and confirms that it works.